# How do I Switch Windows in AppleScript

Tags: window, applescript, applescript-objc

I've just started working on a Applescript project, ( First time I've used AppleScript, Used Objective-C prior )

Now I've made a project in Xcode ( AppleScript Based ) and there's really one thing that I can't figure out. How do I switch windows within the same .xib?

So under MainMenu.xib I have a Window, Which is the RootViewController, and I want to switch to a alternate window when the user presses a push button.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

```
myWindow's orderFront_(me)
```

Take a look at the documentation next time:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html